# mongodb read vs write connection timeout

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to configure different socketTimeout for reads and writes. It is ok if write will be slow but read should be very fast, else I want it to fail.
I know i can configure this inside MongoOptions as following:

```
MongoOptions mongoOptions = new MongoOptions();
mongoOptions.connectionsPerHost = 20;
mongoOptions.threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier = 100;
mongoOptions.maxWaitTime = 1000;
mongoOptions.connectTimeout = 3000;
mongoOptions.socketTimeout = 3000;
mongo = new Mongo(parseServerAddresses("localhost:27017"), mongoOptions);
```

But in this case i have to create two mongo objects  - one for read and one for write operations.

I just did not find this configuration in query level, Or for collection level but split the definitions for read and write.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're right-- you would need two different instances of Mongo to do this. There is no way to pass in a socket timeout in options parameter.

Answer (score -1):

> I just did not find this configuration in query level.

In terms of setting this for a specific query, the Java driver has the following signature on the `find()` method [here](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.7.0/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html):

```
find(DBObject query, DBObject fields, int numToSkip, int batchSize, int options)
```

That `options` setting should allow you to set query options such as the socket timeout for a specific query.

The method above is marked as deprecated, but you can also set the [options on a specific cursor](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.7.0/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html#setOptions%28int%29).

> I want to configure different socketTimeout for reads and writes. It is ok if write will be slow but read should be very fast, else I want it to fail.

Note that reading can incur several reads on the socket. Documents are returned from the server in batches. So you may get your first 100 results really fast, but then you may time out on the next 100 results.

If your queries involves lots of Documents coming back, you should be aware of this.

Comment: I saw such options, but what is the constants for them? For example for using slaveOk i'm using db.getCollection("someColl").addOption(Bytes.QUERYOPTION_SLAVEOK). I did not find the constants for query and how can i update several options ?

Comment: Could you please give an example of such query with setting establishConnectionTimeout and socketTimeout